# Custom Bow Pulling Animation Not Showing - Minecraft Forge for 1.7.10

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm creating a very basic extension of the `ItemBow`. Right now, I'm just trying to change the textures for my new bow. I have the "standby" icon working correctly, but when shooting the bow, I don't get the "pulling" icons to cycle through for the animation.

Below is a small screencast of the lack of animation. As you can see, the "standby" icon is present through the entire shot. The animation never cycles through the 3 "pulling" icons.

http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c2lfr0e0Ze

Here is my class:

```
package com.swatkins.firstmod;

import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.Side;
import cpw.mods.fml.relauncher.SideOnly;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.texture.IIconRegister;
import net.minecraft.creativetab.CreativeTabs;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemBow;
import net.minecraft.util.IIcon;

public class DiamondBow extends ItemBow {

   public static final String[] bowPullIconNameArray = new String[] {"diamond_bow_pulling_0", "diamond_bow_pulling_1", "diamond_bow_pulling_2"};
    @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    private IIcon[] iconArray;

   public DiamondBow()
   {
      setUnlocalizedName(FirstMod.MODID + "_" + "diamond_bow");
   }

   @Override
   @SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
    public void registerIcons(IIconRegister p_94581_1_)
    {
        this.itemIcon = p_94581_1_.registerIcon(FirstMod.MODID + ":" + "diamond_bow_standby");
        this.iconArray = new IIcon[bowPullIconNameArray.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.iconArray.length; ++i)
        {
            this.iconArray[i] = p_94581_1_.registerIcon(FirstMod.MODID + ":" + bowPullIconNameArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

I know there is a `getItemIconForUseDuration` method, but it is never called when holding down the right mouse button to shoot the bow. I've also tried implementing a `getIcon` method, but it isn't called either.

Can anyone help me to get this animation working? I appreciate your help!

FYI: I have posted this in the minecraft forge forums, but it seems dead there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a custom bow a while ago. While the two methods may not seem necessary, they are. (I deleted them just now to test on my own bow) Here's how I coded the methods:

```
@Override
@SideOnly(Side.CLIENT)
public IIcon getIcon (ItemStack stack, int renderPass, EntityPlayer player, ItemStack usingItem, int useRemaining)
{
    if (usingItem != null)
    {
        int time = 72000 - useRemaining;
        if (time < 8)
            return iconArray[0];
        if (time < 14)
            return iconArray[1];
        return iconArray[2];
    }
    return getIcon(stack, renderPass);
}

@Override
public IIcon getItemIconForUseDuration(int par1)
{
    return this.iconArray[par1];
}
```

Hope this helps!

EDIT: I found where getItemIconForUseDuration() is called. In EntityPlayer.class, getItemIcon() calls it.

Comment: Thank you so much. Just adding these two methods (exactly as you have them here) did the job. Thanks so much for the help!!